# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths while installing Oracle WebLogic 12c Infrastructure Installer

Tags: oracle, exception, zip, weblogic12c, oracle12c

I got the following exception while installing Oracle WebLogic 12c Infrastructure Installer to my virtual-box oracle linux os Please help!

> oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPIException:
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths  at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAPIInstaller.doOperation(OiicAPIInstaller.java:1004)
>     at
>   oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.action.NextGenOUIInstaller.start(NextGenOUIInstaller.java:391)
>     at
>   oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.action.NextGenInstallManager.launchOUI(NextGenInstallManager.java:158)
>     at
>   oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.InstallModule.launchOUI(InstallModule.java:164)
>     at
>   oracle.as.install.engine.modules.install.InstallModule$1.run(InstallModule.java:261)
>   Caused by: oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths  at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession.doOperation(OiicInstallAPISession.java:500)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicAPIInstaller.doOperation(OiicAPIInstaller.java:971)
>     ... 4 more Caused by:
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbEndIterateException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths  at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijNextGenCopyPhase.copyNextGenCompFiles(OiijNextGenCopyPhase.java:145)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifw.OiifwInstallPhaseWCCE$OiifwComponentIP1WCCE.doOperation(OiifwInstallPhaseWCCE.java:2115)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbCondIterator.iterate(OiifbCondIterator.java:171)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifw.OiifwInstallPhaseWCCE.doOperation(OiifwInstallPhaseWCCE.java:1023)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbCondIterator.iterate(OiifbCondIterator.java:171)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifw.OiifwActionsPhaseWCDE.doOperation(OiifwActionsPhaseWCDE.java:699)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbLinearIterator.iterate(OiifbLinearIterator.java:147)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicNextGenInstallAPISession$OiicNextGenAPISelCompsInstall.doOperation(OiicNextGenInstallAPISession.java:434)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiif.oiifb.OiifbCondIterator.iterate(OiifbCondIterator.java:171)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession.doInstallAction(OiicInstallAPISession.java:689)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession.access$000(OiicInstallAPISession.java:91)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicInstallAPISession$OiicActionsThread.run(OiicInstallAPISession.java:973)
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193)   at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)    at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiix.OiixFileOps.copyStream(OiixFileOps.java:1549)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijFastJarExtracter.copyFileFromJar(OiijFastJarExtracter.java:337)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijNextGenJarExtracter.copyFileFromJar(OiijNextGenJarExtracter.java:433)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijFastJarExtracter.extractEntry(OiijFastJarExtracter.java:272)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijNextGenJarExtracter.copyJarContents(OiijNextGenJarExtracter.java:229)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijNextGenJarExtracter.extract(OiijNextGenJarExtracter.java:421)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijNextGenCopyPhase.extractJar(OiijNextGenCopyPhase.java:208)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijNextGenCopyPhase.processComponentJars(OiijNextGenCopyPhase.java:167)
>     at
>   oracle.sysman.oii.oiij.OiijNextGenCopyPhase.copyNextGenCompFiles(OiijNextGenCopyPhase.java:136)
>     ... 11 more

What is wrong in here? I have java 7_51. Ultimately i wanted to install Oracle Enterprise Repository 12c.

Comment: It looks like there's a corrupt block in the file. I suggest that you delete the installer, download it again, and try the install again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the installer, downloaded it again then issue got sorted.